# Install WIFI Driver for external usb adapter using terminal

Tags: drivers

I bought an external usb wifi adapter for ubuntu. It came up with a CD with driver files,but I dont know how to install it (as I am new on linux).Can someone please help?? I am uploading some images as it might help.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hw3YfTDeGCTU6lj4k6ZhO33RY8rSpMR4?usp=sharing

Edit: Here I am uploading install.sh file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hSbdS_aiw54CZUjzybMIgkAzXL8G23Ub/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if you double-click install? Is that a Windows MSI?

Comment: Try reading the readme.txt file on the disc.

Comment: I have added install.h on drive, please if someone understands can explain it?